# comparing sorted or removed rows in dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid to dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: dojo

I've scoured the dojo documentation, stack overflow, as well as thoroughly explored the EnhancedGrid object itself with firebug, and I'm not finding answers.

I have an enhanced grid that I populate with values for the user to sort on and basically create a selection set (using indirectSelection plugin). They then have a button to zoom to the selected items on a map.

The problem is, when sorting columns, it doesn't change the order of the items in the store itself, where I'm keeping an object inside each item that tells me how to zoom on the map, so I have no way to reconcile the `grid.selection.selected` array indices with the `store._arrayOfAllItems` indices.

edit: Note that I'm stuck using Dojo 1.6 as it's baked into the API I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Dojo Object Store Tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/intro_dojo_store/).

You can set an idProperty to a Store, e.g.:

```
var employeeStore = new dojo.store.Memory({data:employees, idProperty: "name"});
```

Then you can operate the store with that id property using the get method like this:

```
// add a new employee
employeeStore.add({name:"George", department:"accounting"});
// remove Bill
employeeStore.remove("Bill");
// retrieve object with the name "Jim"
var jim = employeeStore.get("Jim");
```

Instead of using `store._arrayOfAllItems`. That way your `grid.selection` object will contain your id's values instead of array indexes (provided that your grid's store property is your store). This is the part that I'm guessing will work because I know for sure that the new dojo's [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) does it that way, which I encourage you to use it BTW.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I get what you mean with that being a better way to access the item(s) in the store. In Dojo 1.6 it's `store.fetchItemByIdentity()`

Is `idProperty` a 1.7 thing? I tried adding that and my `grid.selection` still populates as `[true, false, true, true, false]`

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by adding an ID column to the grid, and using `dojo.query("#queryGrid .dojoxGridRowSelected [idx$=\"1\"]")` to find the selected rows' ids, to compare to the store. Not so pretty, but it's getting it done for now. Thanks for the help, this is my first post, am I allowed to vote you up? It pointed me in the right direction :P

Comment: haha, you're welcome @mbuna . It's one of my first posts too. So I'm not really sure either :) . In 1.7 that idProperty has worked for me in the past.